# Need to select specific row and a specific column within that row and compare it with a php variable

Tags: php, mysql

This is my block of code for doing that. It works fine until it reaches the last if statement. I cannot get it to find the Graphics column using the Department_ID. I am trying to check if the user input is equal to a id within the table. Then check if that id requires graphic work done. To do that, I need to find out that for that specific project graphic is a 1 in the database.

```
if($graphics_id != Null)
{   
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM Project_Overview WHERE Project_ID='".$graphics_id."'"); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    //echo $row['Project_ID'];

    if($graphics_id == $row['Project_ID']) //if the graphics_id matches a project_id in the table
    {
        $result =  mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT Graphics FROM Department WHERE Department_ID ='".$graphics_id."'")
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($result)
        {
            echo $row['Department_ID'];
        } else {
            echo "This Project does not require graphics!"
        }   
    } else {
        echo "Project_ID ".$graphics_id." does not exist!";
    }       
}
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  You should just have a single query that performs a join instead of performing independent queries and trying to loop through all the results in your code.  Also, the `SELECT *` in your first query is typically not a good idea.  You'd want to select only the columns you actually need.

Comment: @ThomasEllis thanks for the advice. I have already started to look up how to use JOIN. The code I have works all the way up to the if statement. The  question is how can I get to row 8, the graphics column and get the value that is there to check if it is a 1 or 0? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- The second SELECT Statement selects the `Graphics` column, but later you are echoing `$row['Department_ID'];` which should be empty as the only key in `$row` would be `Graphics`
- The last if-Statement is `if($result)`. Don't you mean `if($row)`? If `$result` is false (and hence "This Project does not require graphics!" is printed out), this would indicate, that `mysqli_query` has failed, possibly because of an error in your second SQL statement.
- And, as ThomasEllis said, a JOIN would be nicer and `SELECT *` is not wrong but returns (probably) more than you need.
- Depending on where `$graphics_id` comes from (a user input?) you should consider escaping it for security reasons (`$graphics_id_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $graphics_id);` - just in case ;)